# Digital value calculation clarification

Tags: audio, math

I've done some math and I'd like someone to clarify if my math is right. I  have a audio test chamber which the speaker is connected to and can tell me the dBSPL value that the speaker outputs.

So i have speaker who's datasheet shows that at 1 kHz,
[image]

a 100mVrms provides a 106 dB SPL sound.

I did a practical setup, where the speaker is attached to a 24bit DSP chip. In the DSP chip, i generate a +-1 time domain signal (1kHz) that passes through a DAC ( 0 dB gain) and the speaker outputs that sound.

I measured the voltage value at the speaker terminals, which is 0.944 Vrms.

This corresponds to = 106+20*log10(0.944/0.1) = 125.4994 dB SPL.

in order to find the digital equivalent of 106 dB SPL that i should generate in the DSP,

```
20*log10(0.944) = -0.500560114038621 dBVrms 
20*log10(100e-3) = -20 dBVrms 
-20-(-0.500560114038621) = -19.499439885961380  
10^(-19.499439885961380/20) = 0.105932203389831
```

In the time domain of the DSP, if i generate a 1 kHz sine wave
with +- 0.1059 , i get a 101 dB SPL (not the 106 dB SPL sound that i expected).

Im at a loss to explain where the 5 dB went missing. The Audio Test chamber works correctly because i have used a calibrated sound generator which the test chamber confirms. I wanted to know if my math is correct or not. If anyone else can give a possible explanation as to why i might be missing 5 dB , I'm all ears.

Comment: You need to excite the speaker with a sine wave source not a square wave. {lease link the speaker data sheet.

Comment: I did create a sine wave . Not a square wave

Comment: It's just that you said this: *i generate a +-1 time domain signal* <-- sounds like a square wave to me. Please link the speaker data sheet (again).

Comment: Did you actually get 106 dB SPL with 100mVrms, or do you just believe the data sheet? Are you using the same measurement method that is used for datasheet measurements? What distance you use from speaker to measuring microphone?

Comment: @Andyaka I have edited and added the datasheet to the original Q.

Comment: @Justme - Yeah, the set up is different. We are using a different coupler. But i was mostly interested to see if my math was right or if there's a mistake in any of my calculations.